# Most sophisticated CSS rendering bug of all time (IE9)

Tags: css, rendering, internet-explorer-9

Take a look at this in IE9:

http://jsfiddle.net/dalgard/n6PDB/show/

screen dump:
[image]

Read these comments:

```
/*
 *  IE9: Upon moving the mouse a ghostly 1px vertical line appears 53px into the
 *  blue area - only works with normalized CSS (!?) and not inside an iframe
 */

#test {
  width: 152px;             /* must be 152px or larger! */
  height: 200px;            /* can be any height */
  border-radius: 1px;       /* must be 1px or larger */
  background-color: #44f;   /* ghost-line becomes invisible with #00f */
}

#test:hover {}              /* removing this makes the line disappear */

#test div {
  opacity: 0;               /* removing this makes the line disappear */
  position: relative;       /* removing this makes the line disappear */
  left: 53px;               /* must be 53px or smaller! */
  width: 10px;              /* must be 1px or larger */
  height: 150px;            /* height of the ghost-line */
}
```

Does anyone have any opinion on this?? What is going on and how can I report this? How do I keep this from happening (I know, it seems I could just change ANY of the attributes in the above, however it's not so easy...)?

Comment: or you can use http://jsfiddle.net/dalgard/n6PDB/show/

Comment: Oh, and the line disappears if I change to another tab and then change back. It reappears after moving the mouse, though.

Comment: (Thanks for the "show" feature - great)

Comment: yw :) it is really useful, but as for the bug, I can't reproduce it.

Comment: The line is *quite* difficult to see as it is semi-transparent. Will add a screen dump.

Comment: I've seen similar bugs in Chrome and Firefox recently. Either all of the major browser writers are making similar mistakes while getting ready for CSS3, or something else is going on.

Answer (score 1):

the line has to do with the border of the parent container AND the inner div.  If you get rid of the inner div OR the border it resolves the issue.  I don't know if this will help but that's what appears to be the problem.

Comment: Did you notice how changing ANY of the values, including putting the whole thing in an iframe, makes the line go away? What makes you come to your conclusion?

Comment: I would call it a render bug in IE but I noticed that if I disabled the left border value in the IE webdev tools that the render problem disappeared.  I also noticed that the render problem appears to fire on the left edge of where the inner div is sitting in the block, and that on mouse over (which shouldn't do anything) the render line appears.  So I would trouble shoot the border first since that is the least likely to be noticed if changed.

Answer (score 0):

I can see the issue on IE9 
Version: 9.0.4 ([KB2618444](http://support.microsoft.com/?id=2618444))

but it seems to be fixed on
Version: 9.0.24 ([KB2909921](http://support.microsoft.com/?id=2909921))