# Why is there a thin vertical line in my table cell in IE9 only?

Tags: html, css, html-table, internet-explorer-9, cell

Here is my test code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <style type="text/css">
        table
        {
            border-collapse: collapse;              
        }
        td
        {
            background-color: gray;             
        }
        td.first
        {
            -webkit-border-bottom-left-radius: 10px;
            -moz-border-radius-bottomleft: 10px;
            border-bottom-left-radius: 10px;
            width: 100px;               
        }
        td.second
        {
            -webkit-border-bottom-right-radius: 10px;
            -moz-border-radius-bottomright: 10px;
            border-bottom-right-radius: 10px;               
            width: 100px;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <table>
        <tbody>
            <tr>                    
                <td>Column 1</td>
                <td>Column 2</td>                       
                <td>Column 3</td>                       
                <td>Column 4</td>                       
            </tr>           
            <tr>                    
                <td class="first"></td>
                <td class="second" colspan="3">Column 2</td>                        
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</body>
```

This only occurs in IE9. If I add some padding, remove the border radius in td.second, or add a cell and change the colspan, it disappears (for this sample anyway). I have another project where doing the same isn't feasible or just doesn't work.

What is causing this to happen and is there some magical CSS I can use that can fix it for IE9 and not break and other browser?

Comment: Same thing as here, I think: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7458393/most-sophisticated-css-rendering-bug-of-all-time-ie9. In that question, it looks like an IE9 bug.

Comment: Running your code in jsFiddle and I'm not seeing it: http://jsfiddle.net/PytgZ/ But I see it if I run it from my local machine. Odd.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Played around with it a bit and I have to confirm thirtydot's conclusion that it's a display bug. If you take out the colspan or change the second row to:

```
<tr>                    
    <td class="first">X</td>
    <td colspan="2">Column 2</td>
    <td class="second">&nbsp;</td>                        
</tr>
```

Then no more line. Probably having to something to do with the corner radius not rendering correctly, since it's a new feature for IE.

Comment: I'm giving up. This seems like a rendering bug, unfortunately. Thank you for your help invertedSpear.